# Cannot create bash alias with macos (mojave)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, macos-mojave

I just moved to a mac and would like to transfer much of my `.bashrc` from linux, seems as though the migration will not work all at once smoothly, so trying to piece it together.
Right now I added a few simple commands and I am getting errors.
Here is my `.bash_profile`:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
alias admin="npm start"
alias r='source ~/.bash_profile'
##export ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME="bla-bla-bla"
##export ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL="http://some number"
```

What I am getting is:

```
-bash: alias admin=npm start: command not found
-bash: alias r=source ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure you made those changes in `~/.bash_profile` ? Also could you tell the output of `type alias` and the output you get when you just type `alias`?

Comment: Pretty sure, I typed `open ~/.bash_profile` then cmd+s

Comment: The only possibility I see for this is that your `nvm.sh` tampered with the builtin `alias` itself.

Comment: @Michael just making sure you have executed or imported dot profile and then tried commands?

Comment: Consider add 'set -x' to the script to get more insight into execution order

Comment: hmm, did not create a `.profile` do I need that?

Comment: If your files where anywhere near an MS-Windows machine, then `dos2unix ~/.bash_profile` etc. may help. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry if out of place here, as this isn't answering your question, but I'd definately take a look at `zsh` and [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) if you're just starting your Mac journey.